# NHibernate Naming Conventions - Eliminate Keyword Conflicts

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, naming-conventions

How do I escape keyword conflicts when NHibernate generates my column names using FluentNHibernate?

NHibernate generated this for me and "Key" is a conflict.

```
create table Setting (
       Key NVARCHAR(MAX) not null,
       Value NVARCHAR(MAX) null,
       primary key (Key)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  The fix is to use FluentNHibernate's Column property part to put brackets around the column name for the key property.

Here is an entity with a problematic Key property:

```
public class MyEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Key { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is how to specify the column name in the mapping:

```
public class MyEntityMap : ClassMap<MyEntity>
    {
        public MyEntityMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

            // Note the brackets around Key
            Map(x => x.Key).Column("[Key]").Not.Nullable();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table Setting (
       [Key] NVARCHAR(MAX) not null,
       Value NVARCHAR(MAX) null,
       primary key (Key)
)
```

SQL Server allows you to escape reserved words by putting square brackets around the text.

Comment: How do I tell NHiberate to do that?

Comment: Put names (of tables, fields) in backticks: `Setting`, `Key`. In fluent, you may want conventions to do that.

Comment: @queen3 how do i do that for all of them?

Comment: Oops, SO ate my backticks ;-) Anyway, I think FNH should use backticks everywhere by default according to http://www.mail-archive.com/fluent-nhibernate@googlegroups.com/msg00683.html, but it used to change so often...

Comment: @queen3 i think its changed since then.

Comment: You may also want to override, for example, IPropertyConvention to setup column (property) names. The topic is already described in FNH wiki.